# how to override a one line with the other line using JCL

Tags: sorting, jcl, dfsort

Below is my query: 
[image: Picture 1]

In the first picture the 0 is present in the first line, that zero needs to be added in the second line as shown in the second picture

[image: picture2]

Comment: Can you elaborate more in terms of what you want to do ?  Are you looking to take the three lines as input and end up with two as output ?

Comment: As i attached the first picture tit is the input file , it contains 0 in the first line  and in second line there a PUT statement, and the output should look like in second picture that means 0 should be appended in the second line at position 50 in the output file.

Answer (score 1):

Interactively using ISPF Edit place a `M` on line `000001` and an `O` on line `000002`.   Although, its not in JCL.

Are you looking for a utility that can be run as a step in a batch job to do this automatically ?

`IEBUPDTE` is described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.idau100/iebupdt.htm) to do what you are describing in batch.  Unfortunately, given the lack of detail in the original post I can't really craft an example.

Comment: Yes im looking for a step in batch job to do this automatically.